# How do I (or can I safely, or may I) move a const object?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Consider [this](https://ideone.com/8xzfSz) code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Movable {
public:
    Movable(const string& name) : m_name(name) { }
    Movable(const Movable& rhs) {
        cout << "Copy constructed from " << rhs.m_name << endl;
    }

    Movable(Movable&& rhs) {
        cout << "Move constructed from " << rhs.m_name << endl;
    }

    Movable& operator = (const Movable& rhs) {
        cout << "Copy assigned from " << rhs.m_name << endl;
    }

    Movable& operator = (Movable&& rhs) {
        cout << "Move assigned from " << rhs.m_name << endl;
    }

private:
    string m_name;
};


int main() {
    Movable obj1("obj1");
    Movable obj2(std::move(obj1));
    obj2 = std::move(obj1);     // For demostration only

    const Movable cObj("cObj");
    Movable tObj(std::move(cObj));
    tObj = std::move(cObj);     // For demonstration only
}
```

Its output is:

```
Move constructed from obj1
Move assigned from obj1
Copy constructed from cObj
Copy assigned from cObj
```

As you can see, in these lines,

```
Movable tObj(std::move(cObj));
tObj = std::move(cObj);     // For demonstration only
```

I intend to move `cObj` to `tObj` (the second move using the assignment operator is purely intended for demonstration). However, as you can see in the output, `cObj` is only *copied* to `tObj`.

The above example is only a demonstration and I do not know of any practical usage for this. But I will ask:

1. Can I move a `const` object?
2. If I can, is it safe to do it?

**ADDITIONAL:** I forgot to ask. If I can move a `const` object, *how* should I do it? (`const_cast`?)

Comment: I don't know if you know already, but it's being copied instead of moved because your constructor takes a `Movable&&` but `std::move` gives it a `const Movable&&` which can only be taken by the `const Movable&` overload.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Yes. I have that idea but I'm not very sure of it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You should never use `const_cast` if you can avoid it.  @Seth is right: You need a constructor that takes a const rvalue reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, as long as the object's non-`mutable` state doesn't change as a result of being moved from.

Perhaps you have an object that corresponds to file content, or a database record.  And it caches that data when accessed, in a `mutable` member.  Now, you could move that object by stealing its cached data, without actually modifying the object.  So it would make sense (insofar as it makes sense for the object to be movable at all) for that object to have move constructor and move assignment operator that take `const Record&&`.

This is perfectly legal, section 12.8p3 of the C++11 Standard provides that:

> A non-template constructor for class `X` is a move constructor if its first parameter is of type `X&&`, **`const X&&`**, `volatile X&&`, or `const volatile X&&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments.

and p19:

> A user-declared move assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static non-template member function of class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X&&`, **`const X&&`**, `volatile X&&`, or `const volatile X&&`.

In this way, you could move a `const` object, `reopen` the new <strike>copy</strike> whatever-you-call-an-instance-created-via-move, thus reusing the buffer space for something else and avoiding a new allocation, while leaving the old object intact and ready to return its content (by hitting the disk or database again) if required.

Comment: Can you think of an example where this would be useful in practice?

Comment: @Nemo: Was editing as you commented.  Is that a sane example?

Comment: @BenVoigt Right. So only the `mutable` members get moved.

Comment: I guess (+1).  I thought the intent of a "move constructor" was to leave the source object in a "valid but unspecified" state. But if the source is a const rvalue reference, I suppose the intent is for the move constructor to leave the object in a "valid and semantically unchanged" state?  Seems a bit contrived, but apparently the language allows it.

Comment: @Nemo: Correct.  "valid but unspecified" is the *minimum* that moving should do.  There's nothing preventing a particular object from making a stronger guarantee.

Comment: Well, I learned something new today, so I can sleep well tonight.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your code the copy constructor is called as the move-constructor requires a non-const argument (`Movable&&`), while the argument is a const object (`std::move(cObj)` is of type `const Movable&&`). Since the non-const rvalue-reference cannot bind the const rvalue, that overload is discarded and the next best match is the copy constructor.

Now the next question is whether/when can you move out of a `const` object. While technically you can implement a move constructor that takes a `const &&` and you can even do that without invoking undefined behavior (just don't modify any non-mutable member of the source object) the question is whether it makes sense. And I don't think it does.

The presence of a move constructor is usually an indication that there is a resource that is maintained by the object that can be efficiently transferred to another object when the source object is no longer needed (for example, when constructing an object out of a temporary). Moving is *inherently* modifying the source object. A move constructor that does not modify the source object *cannot* move a resource from the source object to the destination object, and it makes little or no sense at all.

Comment: I agree it will be exceptionally rare, but doesn't my answer provide a counter-example to your final claim?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Not really, I am not sure that example makes a whole lot of sense. In particular, consider what the state of the source *and* destination objects is after the move. Assuming that you only move the *mutable* cache, that means that the source object still holds the resource from which the data was read, and the destination type only holds the cached data, but not the resource from which it was read. While the former could make sense, the latter does not. I don't think I would accept that in a code review, if you just want to pull the cached data out, provide a member function.

Comment: Why couldn't the second object be linked to the same source?  (e.g. same filename / primary key)  Any handle / `FILE*` / database connection is also just ephemeral data for accessing the content, and probably also stored in a `mutable` variable.

Comment: @BenVoigt: No particular reason, although that operation would not represent *moving* the resource from one object to another, the resouce would be copied, the cache moved. Again, for unnatural semantics I would rather use named members than provide overloads for which there is a common understanding of what they do. A *move* operation that *copies* the resource is not really *moving*. Note that by definition `mutable` members do not take part of the visible state of the object, and thus whether the cache is transferred or not, the visible state is that of a copy.